# How to group entries by date and calculate a percent

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following raw data:

```
df = 

MONTH   DAY   ID    GROUP
1       1     222   1
1       1     111   2
1       2     333   2
...
12      1     XXS   1
```

For each date, I need to calcuate the percent of entries that have `Group` equal to `1`. The result should be a new dataframe in the following format (The date should be `dd/mm/yy`):

```
date,percent
01/01/16,50
02/01/16,0
...
```

I tried this, but it does not give the expected result, because I don't know how to proceed from this point. Not sure how to pass `date` to a single column in the format `dd/mm/yy` and how to calculate the percent of entries having `GROUP == 1`:

```
new_df = df.groupby(['MONTH', 'DAY']).agg(['count'])
```

**UPDATE:**

print(df.types) gives the following output:

```
MONTH                    float64
DAY                      float64
GROUP                    float64
ID                       object
date                     datetime64[ns]
```

This is the sample **real** data:

```
MONTH   DAY GROUP   ID  date
1.0     4.0 2.0 00085163    2016-01-04
1.0     4.0 1.0 000F9334    2016-01-04
1.0     4.0 2.0 002744A2    2016-01-04
1.0     4.0 2.0 00337BB1    2016-01-04
1.0     4.0 2.0 00374DE5    2016-01-04
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** for the `GROUP` column of "float64" dtype

```
In [67]: df
Out[67]:
   MONTH  DAY  GROUP        ID
0    1.0  4.0    2.0  00085163
1    1.0  4.0    1.0  000F9334
2    1.0  4.0    2.0  002744A2
3    1.0  4.0    2.0  00337BB1
4    1.0  4.0    2.0  00374DE5

In [68]: (df.assign(date=pd.to_datetime(df.assign(YEAR=pd.datetime.now().year)
    ...:                                  .loc[:, ['YEAR','MONTH','DAY']])
    ...:                   .dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y'))
    ...:    .groupby('date', as_index=0)['GROUP']
    ...:    .agg({'percent':lambda x: len(np.where(np.isclose(x,1))[0])/x.count()*100})
    ...: )
    ...:
Out[68]:
       date  percent
0  04/01/16     20.0
```

**Old answer for integer GROUP column:**

```
In [40]: df.groupby(['MONTH', 'DAY'], as_index=0)['GROUP'].agg({'percent':lambda x: len(x[x==1])/x.count()*100})
Out[40]:
   MONTH  DAY  percent
0      1    1       50
1      1    2        0
2     12    1      100
```

if you need date as a single column:

```
In [50]: df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.assign(YEAR=pd.datetime.now().year).loc[:, ['YEAR','MONTH','DAY']]).dt.strftime('%d/%m/%y')

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
   MONTH  DAY   ID  GROUP      date
0      1    1  222      1  01/01/16
1      1    1  111      2  01/01/16
2      1    2  333      2  02/01/16
3     12    1  444      1  01/12/16

In [52]: df.groupby('date', as_index=0)['GROUP'].agg({'percent':lambda x: len(x[x==1])/x.count()*100})
Out[52]:
       date  percent
0  01/01/16       50
1  01/12/16      100
2  02/01/16        0
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your solution. One question: For some reason I have `percent` always equal to 0, however if I do `.agg(['count'])`, then I can see values like 3000, 2500, etc. Do you know why zeros could appear when calculating the percent (`x.count()` is non-zero for sure)?

Comment: @Dinosaurius, that means there are no entries where `GROUP==1`

Comment: The funny thing is that I tried to change `GROUP` to 2 (there are only two possible values: `1` and `2`), however again I get percent equal to 0 for all entries.

Comment: Can you provide __reproducible__ sample data set? What is the output of your `print(df.dtypes)`?

Comment: See my update. I think that the issue is related to the float type of `GROUP`, but not sure.

Comment: @Dinosaurius, i've updated my answer - can you check this version?

Comment: I checked and again I get `percent==0` for both `isclose(x,1)` and `isclose(x,2)` for the same dataset as you use. Really cannot understand why does it happen. May it be a bug of pandas? I am using the last version of pandas.

Comment: @Dinosaurius, sorry, i can't reproduce this behaviour. Please ping me if you can reproduce this behaviour with your sample data set. Or in other words if you will be able to find such a sample subset of your data, where you can reproduce this behaviour...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131608/discussion-between-dinosaurius-and-maxu).

Answer (score 0):

This is a very robust solution but it seems to work:

```
temp = df.groupby(['MONTH', 'DAY']).agg({'GROUP': lambda x: float(len(x[x==1]))/x.count()*100}).astype(float).reset_index()

print temp
temp.rename(columns={'GROUP': 'PERCENT'}, inplace=True)
temp['DATE'] = '2016-' + temp['MONTH'].map(int).map(str) + '-' + temp['DAY'].map(int).map(str)
temp['DATE'] = temp['DATE'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))

final = temp[['DATE', 'PERCENT']].set_index('DATE')
```